# How do you open doors on FTL for iPad?

Tags: ios, ftl-faster-than-light

On the desktop version you just click the doors to open them, however on my iPad nothing happens when I tap them.

Is there another way of opening ship doors on the iPad version of the game?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To open doors, just tap the door subsystem; the game will auto-pause (by default) and you'll be able to toggle the doors by either tapping them, or dragging your finger over multiple doors.

[image]

Then just click it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to click on the Door Subsystem in order to enter "door mode" and open/close the doors. You will have a "Close all" and "Open all" buttons.

You could drag along the path to toggle the state of the doors. It is explained on the **Tutorial**. So once Door Subsystem selected you can drag your finger along the closed doors you want to open (for example).